# masking edittext input type to dots

Tags: android

I have a edit text in my activity i don't want to show input to user like when user entering password in to edit text i need to show only dots in edittext is there any way to do that in android

here is my code

```
      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editText1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:ems="10" 
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          android:hint="enter password"/>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
          android:text="Button" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u have option in ADT and android studio for the password widget

Comment: you already mentioned inputType as textPassword. then by default it will show only the dots. it is right or not working

Comment: is ur password consist of numbers or text??

Answer (score 0):

if your password consist of both number and text have to write custom keyBord to handel click events. The above is the code for setting image as String in editText

```
private void insertimgstoedit() {
    String str = "<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin2) + "'/>";
    if (pwdcount == 0) {
        Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("&nbsp;" + str, getter, null);
        medittxtpinEdTxt.setText(cs);
    } else {
        String ss = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= pwdcount; i++) {
            ss = ss + "&nbsp;" + str;
        }
        Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml(ss, getter, null);
        medittxtpinEdTxt.setText(cs);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1" />

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```